# How can I pass special characters [eg. " or ( or ' ] as arguments to shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I got one error while passing the arguments to `outlook_DataParsing.sh`:

```
$ sh outlook_DataParsing.sh delete node doc('/opt/ws40/contacts.xml')//Directory/Contacts/Contact[@id='22222']
```

and I am reading all the arguments as:

```
str=$@
```

The error is following:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of "special" characters in a shell command, including $()[]

Most of these can simply be passed by enclosing the parameter in double quotes

```
foo "(hello)[]"
```

This however will not fix the $ sign, as it is intended for variables. You can instead use single quotes to pass a $ sign

```
foo '$im_not_a_variable'
```

If all else fails, ANY character can be escaped with a backslash \ including a space (no quotes needed)

```
foo \(hello\)\[\]\ \$im_not_a_variable
```